# The previous queued operation has not been commited error in ServiceStack Redis Client

Tags: redis, servicestack

I tried to achieve "cascaded" Store for my article instance in ServiceStack Redis Client. There was only one transaction. Is it a weird error for QueueCommand ? Why I got this error?

```
trans.QueueCommand(p => p.IncrementValue(KeyHelper.GetAutoIncrementKey(article)),
                                   id => article.Id = id);
```

Critic Clue : trans.AddRangeToSet METHOD COULD NOT SET trans.CurrentQueuedOperation TO NULL !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using AddRangeToSet method as empty string list as value. 
I've sent pull request.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/pull/53